# Swashbuckle: generate sensible schema and example for dictionary with Guid keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to make a REST interface.

Swashbuckle handily generates a sensible JSON and schema for `FancyEntity` in another GET request, but  the problem arises when I define a GET request returns a `Dictionary<Guid, FancyEntity>`. I get the following example:

```json
{
  "additionalProp1": {
    "world": "string",
    "sendAt": "2024-02-06T12:46:06.301Z"
  },
  "additionalProp2": {
    "world": "string",
    "sendAt": "2024-02-06T12:46:06.301Z"
  },
  "additionalProp3": {
    "world": "string",
    "sendAt": "2024-02-06T12:46:06.301Z"
  }
}
```

and the schema specifies `< * >:` as the keys.

Is there a way to provide some example Guids instead of `additionalPropN` and get the schema to say `string($uuid)`?

ETA: code is basically this:

```cs
public class HelloWorldController(IUniversalEventService<HelloWorldEvent> service)
    : BaseEventController<HelloWorldEvent>(service)
{
    /* ... */
    [HttpGet(GetAllSchedulesRoute)]
    [ProducesResponseType<Dictionary<Guid, HelloWorldEvent>>((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public override Task<IActionResult> GetAllSchedules(CancellationToken cancel = default) =>
        base.GetAllSchedules(cancel);
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Please also show your c# code

Comment: @tomredfern code added

Comment: What about the code which reflects the schema. The FancyEntity type.

Comment: @tomredfern it's a two-field record of a string and a datetime.